# How to find total login times for a user?

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

Every time a user logs in to my application, a new `sessionID` is created that is unique to the login. If a user logs in once, logs out, and then logs back in they will have a different `sessionID`.

**How do I find the total time that each user has been logged in over the last two weeks?**

My table has `UserName`, `sessionID`, and `timestamp` columns, and a row is inserted into the table for each action performed. I want to sum the difference between the first instance of the `sessionID` and the last instance of the `sessionID` for each session for a user during the last two weeks. Actions outside of the two week time period can be ignored.

Example data:

```
UserName sessionID timestamp 
user1    s1        '2019-07-01 08:00:00.000' 
user1    s1        '2019-07-01 10:00:00.000' 
user2    a1        '2019-07-01 16:00:00.000'
user1    s2        '2019-07-02 08:00:00.000' 
user2    a1        '2019-07-02 09:00:00.000'
user1    s2        '2019-07-02 10:00:00.000'
```

Example result:

```
UserName LoginTime
user1    04:00:00.000
user2    17:00:00.000
```

I was thinking of mapping a `UserName` to every `sessionID` that was associated with the `UserName` and then finding the max and min `timestamp` for each and summing them up, but that would require partitions in which I am hopelessly lost.

Comment: Always best to supply sample data and desired results.   Also, what is the rule for when a user did NOT logout properly?

Comment: Please add what you have tried so we may help you fix it  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: So the database tracks all activity, so if the user did not logout properly then still just find the difference between the first timestamp of the sessionID and the last timestamp. All sessionID's appear at least twice as they appear once upon hitting the login button and once when the user is sent to the home screen

Comment: Please explain what "sum up the difference between" means - sum is quite a different thing from a differential of something

Comment: What I mean by that is that a user likely has multiple sessionIDs over the course of the last 2 weeks, so say the database was something like:

**username** **sessionID** **timestamp**

user1   s1   '2019-07-01 08:00:00.000'
user1   s1   '2019-07-01 10:00:00.000'
user1   s2   '2019-07-02 08:00:00.000'
user1   s2   '2019-07-02 10:00:00.000'

then I want the result to just say: user1 04:00:00.000 by summing up the differences between the max and the min of the two session IDs

Comment: Please edit your question to add the clarifications.  What I infer from all that is you want the total logged in time for each user for the two weeks prior?  And, what if a user logs in or out outside that two week range, do you only want the values where the begin and end both fall within the period? If not, please specify how to handle the one sided time periods.  When you place a question on this site, it is expected that you also provide the actual code you have tried in an attempt to accomplish your task.

Comment: I have edited my post with those specifications and my thought process towards a potential solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example data:

- Both the `Username` and `SessionId` columns have a character data type, which I will mimic using `NVARCHAR(80)`.
- The `Timestamp` column has a date and time data type, which I will mimic using `DATETIME`.

The following SQL creates an example table, populates the table with example data, and calculates the sum of the number of minutes for each session for each user from the last two weeks.

```
CREATE TABLE Session
(
    Username NVARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    SessionId NVARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @date DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, 15, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()));

INSERT INTO Session(Username, SessionId, Timestamp) VALUES
('user1', 's1', DATEADD(HOUR, 8, @date)),
('user1', 's1', DATEADD(HOUR, 10, @date)),
('user1', 's2', DATEADD(HOUR, 32, @date)),
('user1', 's2', DATEADD(HOUR, 34, @date)),
('user1', 's3', DATEADD(HOUR, 56, @date)),
('user1', 's3', DATEADD(HOUR, 58, @date)),
('user1', 's4', DATEADD(HOUR, 80, @date)),
('user1', 's4', DATEADD(HOUR, 82, @date)),
('user2', 's5', DATEADD(HOUR, 81, @date)),
('user2', 's5', DATEADD(HOUR, 82, @date)),
('user2', 's6', DATEADD(HOUR, 86, @date)),
('user2', 's6', DATEADD(HOUR, 87, @date));


SELECT Username, SUM(SessionTime)
FROM
(
    SELECT Username, SessionId, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(Timestamp), MAX(Timestamp)) AS SessionTime
    FROM Session
    WHERE Timestamp > DATEADD(WEEK, -2, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY Username, SessionId
) AS S1
GROUP BY Username;
```